# Duplicate elements in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two array list, One is to save name and other is to save quantity. I want to avoid duplicate in the array list. Name array list contains name and its corresponding quantity is contained in quantity array list.

My array list can contains duplicate names, I want to traverse array list to check the name if already exists, if it exists then add the quantity to the previous value and delete duplicate entry.

Eg

```
Name     Quantity
ABC      20
xyz      10
ABC      15
```

**Output Required**

```
Name    Quantity
ABC      35
XYZ      10
```

Thanks

Comment: Previously you said you wanted to delete the old entry, now you are adding them.  Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `Map` instead, which will not allow for duplicate entries.  You use it something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> nameToQuantityMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>():

nameToQuantityMap.put("Mr Smith", 100);
nameToQuantityMap.put("Mrs Jones", 500);
```

**EDIT:** Now that you've edited the question, the answer is different.  If you want to add the values of duplicate keys, you'll have to do something like this:

```
// For each (name, quantity) pair
if (nameToQuantityMap.containsKey(name) ) {
    Integer sum = nameToQuantityMap.get(name) + quantity;
    nameToQuantityMap.put(name, sum);
}
else {
        nameToQuantityMap.put(name, quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to avoid duplicate in the array list.
```

In that case use [**HashSet**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Or else if you have 2 parallel ArrayList then you can use **[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)**

Answer (score 0):

The structure you attempt to represent resembles something that should be represented by a `Map`, which is a key -> value storage type of structure. Having two lists and trying to keep the in sync is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Map` where key would be you map and value would be value.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
if(map.get(name)!=null){
    Integer oValue = map.get(name)+nNalue;
}else
   map.put(name,value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to add value to the previous value if Key already exists .

```
 public class Example {
    static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        insertNameAndQuantity("A", 10);
        insertNameAndQuantity("B", 25);
        insertNameAndQuantity("A", 25);
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static void insertNameAndQuantity(String key, Integer value) {

        Integer count = map.get(key);
        if (count == null)
            map.put(key, value);
        else
            map.put(key, count + value);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
{A=35, B=25}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example implement on c# code.

```
public class temp
{
    [Test]
    public void T()
    {
        var list1 = new ArrayList(){"ABC", "xyz", "ABC"};
        var list2 = new ArrayList() {20, 10, 15};

        var nameList = new List<string>();
        var list1result = new ArrayList();
        var list2result = new ArrayList();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (string name in list1)
        {
            if (!nameList.Contains(name))
            {
                list1result.Add(name);
                var quantity = list2[index] ?? 0;
                list2result.Add(quantity);
                nameList.Add(name);
            }
            else
            {
                var index2 = 0;
                foreach (string name2 in list1result)
                {
                    if (name2 == name)
                    {
                        list2result[index2] = (int)list2result[index2] + (int)list2[index];
                    }
                    index2++;
                }
            }
            index++;
        }

        Assert.True(list1result.Count == 2, list1result.Count + " t1");
    }

}
```

I've tested the output, it's correct.